# html5 canvas draw text with mutiple font

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

How  can i fill text in the canvas with mutiple font.
I can be able to fill in canvas this:

This is an  **example** of what I want to do

this is another  *example* of what I want to do

I know that i can slpit the sting and do first fill the normal text, second the bold text, and third the rest of the text. but i want to be able to drag and drop the text, so i cant do in that way.

Comment: and how will you drag and drop text, since canvas doesn't retain what you wrote ?

Comment: @Jocelyn i'm already can do that..
http://jsfiddle.net/h3BCq/1/ here is an example!

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible, I said that you have to manage it yourself, so to answer your question we have to see how you do that :)

Comment: Could you explain why splitting the text is incompatible with the drag and drop ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you're out of luck. There's no easy way out here.

You have to call drawtext at least three times if you want text with a bolded word in the center.

There may be a time in the future where you are allowed to draw arbitrary html, the spec mentions this is a real possibility, but that won't be for some time. To quote the spec:

> Note: A future version of the 2D context API may provide a way to render fragments of documents, rendered using CSS, straight to the canvas. This would be provided in preference to a dedicated way of doing multiline layout.

From [the end of this section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-text-to-the-canvas).

You can of course still drag and drop, you just have to have a list of elements and their locations that make up a "node". Much more complicated objects have been done in the canvas no doubt.